# RegEx pattern with unusual unicode character and word boundaries

Tags: java, regex

I'm stuck with a problem concerning RegEx patterns and I hope somebody would explain it to me:

The task is to match object names and remove them from a description that's stored in one of the object's field. I tried the following expression:

```
    final String description= object.getDescrition();
    final Matcher descriptionMatcher=
        Pattern.compile("\\b" + object.getName() + "\\b", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
            .matcher(description);
```

All works fine until the code encounters a "registered trademark" symbol added to the name: `String name = ObjectName®`

If I remove the last word boundary, it is matched again. What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I improve this code to possibly find every such special case?

**Note**: the trademark sign is *not* separated from the object name via space.

Comment: Do you need to keep the "registred trademark" or any special characters ? If not, there is some solution to remove it before parsing.

Comment: unfortunately the special character has to stay ^^

Comment: Is it always at the end of the word or it could be anywhere ? And object.getName() is it ObjectName® ?

Comment: I could imagine a worst case where such characters might even be on any position. Yes, object.getName() returns the field `name`

Comment: Why do you need to use a regex for this? You have a word and you want to find if it exists? Can you do `Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(object.getName()) + "\\b", Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, change your pattern to:

```
"\\b\\Q" + object.getName() + "\\E(?<=\\b|®)"
```

if you need to deal with more complex cases, use alternations in lookarounds instead of word boundaries. Example:

```
"(?<=\\s|^)\\Q" + object.getName() + "\\E(?=\\s|$)"
```

or

```
"(?<=\\s|^)" + Pattern.quote(object.getName()) + "(?=\\s|$)"
```

Comment: Yes, lookarounds were the way to go. In the end I adjusted your second solution by adding `[\\W&&[^-]]` to the lookahead (because sometimes hyphons are used for abbreviated expressions). Should have thought about it before, it's a great improvement.

Comment: @UnknownId: ok, note that `[\\W&&[^-]]` can be written `[^\\w-]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `®` character is not considered a word character, therefore your `Pattern` will not match.

A quick and dirty solution would be to alternate it with the word boundary, if you only have this case:

```
Pattern.compile("\\b" + object.getName() + "\\b|®"
```

Comment: What if there is other characters than just ® at the end ?

Comment: @JFPicard hence the "quick and dirty" part :)